# Maintain button hover effect when outside of button

Tags: css

Hovering over **btn** should trigger display: block; on **btn2** (which it does), then maintain this hover effect when I move the mouse below and outside of **btn** until I am able to click **btn2** (which it currently doesn't).

I thought I could do this by using margin on btn, but that didn't work.

```css
body {
  background-color: #673ab7;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.btn {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #00bcd4;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  &:hover {
     transform:scale(1.05,1.05)
  }
}

.btn2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 110px;
  left: 50.5%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 55px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    &:hover {
    transform:scale(1.05,1.05)
  }
}

.btn:hover +.btn2{
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    transform: scale(1.05,1.05);
    transform: translate(20px);
  }

.icon {
  color: white;
}

.icon2 {
  color: white;
  width: 26px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="btn"><i class="icon fa fa-link"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="btn2"><i class="icon2 fa fa-edit"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Its better to understand the basic of css may be this video is helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8kK-cA99SA0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `:hover` css to the parent `.container` tag of both items so the hover rules are maintained when moving from one element to the next. This way you are maintaining the hover state when moving from child to child.

I also changed `display:none;` to `visibility:hidden;` and `opacity:0`|`opacity:1` respectively. `display:none' isn't going to animate.

The animation time also allows for a short period of overlap (non :focus) when moving from one element to the other. With some keyframing you can make the move from one to the other a bit cleaner.

```css
body {
  background-color: #673ab7;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.btn {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #00bcd4;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  &:hover {
     transform:scale(1.05,1.05)
  }
}

.btn2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 110px;
  left: 50.5%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 55px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    &:hover {
    transform:scale(1.05,1.05)
  }
}

.container:hover .btn +.btn2{
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    position: absolute;
    transform: scale(1.05,1.05);
    transform: translate(20px);
  }

.icon {
  color: white;
}

.icon2 {
  color: white;
  width: 26px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="btn"><i class="icon fa fa-link"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="btn2"><i class="icon2 fa fa-edit"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to maintain the hover state in the space between btn and btn2? If, perhaps, I wanted the distance to be much further between the two elements.

Comment: You can set the size of the outer container to be larger than the two btn elements. Or you can set an animation with keyframes for btn2 to wait a few moments before transitioning out which would make it time based.